# Dúvida de rotina ajax populando a própria página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Só uma dúvida. No campo URL do ajax, quando eu trabalho com MVC, normalmente eu coloco a action/controller. Bem, no meu caso agora eu tenho uma página asp. O que passa é que o ajax está na mesma página em que eu vou carregar. Estou perguntando isso porque não deu certo aqui, mas como havia um problema no bd e ele não estava sendo carregado, preferi esperar até o pessoal de infra colocar o Oracle no ar, mas é isso mesmo, ou seja, eu coloco a página em que eu estou? Veja o esqueleto. A página se chama `../asp/prs0061a_cons_crossbrowser.asp`. Veja o ajax que eu fiz:

```
function CarregaTabela(){

var str = '';

$.ajax({
    url: '../asp/prs0061a_cons_crossbrowser.asp',//dúvida aqui
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.variável_populada_com_info_do_oracle).each(function () {

            str += 'o_campo_a_ser_populado_na_table';
        })

        $('#id_do_tbody_da_table').html(str);

        str = "";

    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
})
}
```

Pessoal, tenho dois arquivos. `prs0061a.asp` e `prs0061b.asp`. No `prs0061b.asp` tenho essa rotina:

```
set rsPesquisa = rsCursorOracle( CStr(Session("ace_usuario")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_senha")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_ip")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_sistema")),_
                                 CStr(Session("ace_modulo")),_
                                 "prs_rcs_gestao.get_prestador_tipo", _
                                 vetPL, _
                                 false )
```

A variável `rsPesquisa` é preenchida com o que vem do Oracle. No outro arquivo, `prs0061a.asp`, tenho o meu ajax:

```
function CarregaTabela(){

var str = '';

$.ajax({
    url: '../asp/prs0061a_cons_crossbrowser.asp',//dúvida aqui
    datatype: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.variável_populada_com_info_do_oracle).each(function () {

            str += 'o_campo_a_ser_populado_na_table';
        })

        $('#id_do_tbody_da_table').html(str);

        str = "";

    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
})
```

}

Como eu faço para pegar a variável carregada do banco e descarregar na tabela citada? Editei a pergunta, pois da forma anterior estava meio confusa. Caso haja a necessidade de uma nova pergunta, mas acho que a edição melhorou minha dúvida.

Comment: Você verificou no console do `browser` se recebe algum erro?

Comment: @Randrade, boa tarde. Não. No meu caso agora o oracle está off, não posso afirmar nada, mas quando eu fiz essa função, já fiz com essa dúvida, se está certo ou não a forma como eu fiz. Veja, a função e o formulário a ser carregado estão no mesmo arquivo.